# Calling Restful Services Dynamically

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have an existing orchestration which calls the services with the below configuration.

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("ABC", Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName));
varNewSearchDataLoadURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewSearchDataLoadURL"];
varNewXmlMsg = new System.Xml.XmlDocument(); 
varNewXmlMsg.LoadXml(@"<path>" + Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName) + @"</path>");
Message_NewUnZip = varNewXmlMsg;
Message_NewUnZip(HTTP.RequestTimeout) = 3600;
Port_NewJaxMiceSearch_API(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = varNewSearchDataLoadURL + "?path=" + Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName);
Port_NewJaxMiceSearch_API(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "HTTP"
```

Here NewSearchDataLoadURL holds the address of the webservice that needs to be called in the config file.And the path holds the received file name.So the called URI will be "[http://new.abc.org/AbcSearchWebApi/api/search/loaddatafeed?path=\share01](http://new.abc.org/AbcSearchWebApi/api/search/loaddatafeed?path=%5Cshare01)\BizTalk\data\out\20150723"

Now I have to change that to the Restful services which uses WebHttp Adapter. I am trying to follow the here

but I dont understand the BtsVariablePropertyMapping because I dont have schema that has the value to be promoted. How can I approach this.
[image]
 Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works, without using the BtsVariablePropertyMapping

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("ABC",   Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName));
varNewSearchDataLoadURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewSearchDataLoadURL"];
varNewXmlMsg = new System.Xml.XmlDocument(); 
varNewXmlMsg.LoadXml(@"<path>" +     Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName) + @"</path>");
Message_NewUnZip = varNewXmlMsg;
Message_NewUnZip(WCF.HttpMethodAndUrl) = @"<BtsHttpUrlMapping><Operation Name = 'RESTGet' Method ='GET'/></BtsHttpUrlMapping>";
Port_NewSearch_API(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = varNewSearchDataLoadURL + "?path=" +      Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName);
Port_NewSearch_API(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "WCF-WebHttp";
Message_NewUnZip(WCF.SuppressMessageBodyForHttpVerbs) = "GET";
```

Answer (score 0):

So your goal is to call a Rest WebService using a dynamic port, in order to do this you need to 
1 - Specifiy your type of operation

```
 <BtsHttpUrlMapping>
  <Operation Name=’MyRestGET’ Method=’GET’ Url=’/XXXX/{EmpId}’ />
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

2 - Create and Map your variables :
"BtsVariablePropertyMapping" is a powerful BizTalk technique that enables you to define **a custom variable in your url** and map it to any **context property using its name and namespace**
So you must definitely have the property schema unless it's a BizTalk context property hence its schema is already present in BizTalk

3 - Init your dynamic port with the webservice url 
In this step you assign your webservice url and transport type in your dynamic solicit response port

```
Microsoft.XLangs.BaseTypes.Adress = /XXXX/{EmpId}
Microsoft.XLangs.Basetypes.TransportType = "WCF-WebHTTP"
```

And you are good to go with this

Comment: I dont understand about the BtsVariablePropertyMapping here I dont have any thing in the schema that needs to be promoted for URL. The URL I am giving is like, `Port_NewSearch_API(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = varNewSearchDataLoadURL + "?path=" + Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName);` Here what do I promote. varNewSearchDataLoadURL holds "http://new.abc.org/AbcSearchWebApi/api/search/loaddatafeed in the webconfig file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have added in my question.

Comment: You have to create a property schema for the adapter to use.  It will set the request message based on those properties.

Comment: @Dan Field can you please explain in detail. Do I create a schema with  a field. Here how do I pass the value of the Received File name in to the Schema field.Also URL address going to have three things right

 varNewSearchDataLoadURL + "?path=" + Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName);

Comment: I have created a other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611433/calling-restful-services because I could not add the code I am trying now.

Comment: @mahieddinecherif I am calling the rest service dynamically. so I dont see anything in the Send port created.

Comment: check this https://masteringbiztalkserver.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/calling-restful-service-using-dynamic-send-ports-biztalk-2013/ this is the solution with all the details you need