# Calling RestFul Services

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am trying to call the RestFull Services from BizTalk 2013 R2. I am trying to change the existing one using Http adapter and use Wcf-WebHttp Adapter

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("ABC",   Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName));
varNewSearchDataLoadURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewSearchDataLoadURL"];
varNewXmlMsg = new System.Xml.XmlDocument(); 
varNewXmlMsg.LoadXml(@"<path>" +   Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName) + @"</path>");
Message_NewUnZip = varNewXmlMsg;
Message_NewUnZip(WCF.HttpMethodAndUrl) = @"<BtsHttpUrlMapping><Operation Name = 'RESTGet' Method ='GET'/></BtsHttpUrlMapping>";
Port_NewSearch_API(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = varNewSearchDataLoadURL + "?path=" +    Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName);
Port_NewSearch_API(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "WCF-WebHttp";
Message_NewUnZip(WCF.SuppressMessageBodyForHttpVerbs) = "GET";
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Can I call without using the BtsVariablePropertyMapping without creating a schema and promoting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works, without using the BtsVariablePropertyMapping

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("ABC",   Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName));
varNewSearchDataLoadURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewSearchDataLoadURL"];
varNewXmlMsg = new System.Xml.XmlDocument(); 
varNewXmlMsg.LoadXml(@"<path>" +   Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName) + @"</path>");
Message_NewUnZip = varNewXmlMsg;
Message_NewUnZip(WCF.HttpMethodAndUrl) = @"<BtsHttpUrlMapping><Operation Name = 'RESTGet' Method ='GET'/></BtsHttpUrlMapping>";
Port_NewSearch_API(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = varNewSearchDataLoadURL + "?path=" +    Message_Datasheets(FILE.ReceivedFileName);
Port_NewSearch_API(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "WCF-WebHttp";
Message_NewUnZip(WCF.SuppressMessageBodyForHttpVerbs) = "GET";
```